# adding elements to listview using templates in appcelerator

Tags: listview, appcelerator

This is my .xml file for creating a listview and adding elements in it using a template in appcelerator. How to style the contents in the list item in .tss file. for eg. I want the image to be on the extreme left and the title to be in the middle below which will be the date and the url.

```
    <Alloy>
        <Window id="win2" class="container">
            <View id = "v1" class ="view1"  layout ="horizontal" >
                <Button class="btnBack" ></Button>
                <Label  class = "label1">List</Label>
            </View>
            <View class="view2">
                <TextField id = "txtSearch"></TextField>
            </View>
            <ListView id = "lView" class = "list1" >
                <Templates>
                    <ItemTemplate name="template">
                        <ImageView bindId="pic" id="iconId" />
                        <Label bindId="info" id="titleId" />
                        <Label bindId="date" id="dateId" />
                        <Label bindId="url" id ="urlId" /> 
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </Templates>
<ListSection>
                        <ListItem pic:image="/Images/abstract-logo-with-colorful-leaves_1025-695.jpg" info:text ="This is the title" date:text= "6/30/2017" url:tex ="https://youtu.be/zkOSR0ZRb9k"></ListItem>
                    </ListSection>
            </ListView>

        </Window>
    </Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the *Alloy XML Markup* section in the [ListView documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ListView).  and note how the sample `index.tss` references each control within the ItemTemplate by its `id`.  The example there is pretty close to what you are trying to accomplish:

```
"#icon" : {
  width: '50dp', height: '50dp', left: 0
},
"#title" : {
  color: 'black',
  font: { fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize: '20dp', fontWeight:'bold' },
  left: '60dp', top: 0
},
"#subtitle" : {
  color: 'gray',
  font: { fontFamily:'Arial', fontSize: '14dp' },
  left: '60dp', top: '25dp'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the ID of the objects to place/style the item. For example in your tss:

```
"#iconId" : {left : 5},
"#titleId" : {left: 100},
"#dateId" : {left: 100},
"#urlId" : {left: 100}
```

You can adjust as needed.